# MySQL match against 'ch' in utf8_czech_ci

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, collation, full-text-indexing

We are successfully using `MATCH AGAINST` in queries to search in our database, which is mostly in Czech, so we use `utf8_czech_ci` as default collation. We have set minimum length of query to 1 and we have disabled all the stop words.

However, consider searching for word `Schedule`.

When you write:

- `s` : `Schedule` found
- `sc` : nothing found
- `sch` : `Schedule` found

It looks like it treats `ch` as single character (which is correct in Czech language), but certainly incorrect when we do fulltext search.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, utf8_czech_ci treats `ch` as a single letter, between `h` and `i`.  `Č` and `č` are equal, but come after all `c`.  Similarly for other letters with a Caron.

[*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) provides the collation quirks of various utf8 collations.

I would argue that your observations are correct for *that* collation.  Is "schedule" a Czech word?

To avoid it, pick another utf8 `COLLATION` for the column, and rebuild the `FULLTEXT` index.  `utf8_bin` and `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci` are likely candidates.  You may need to have two columns (and indexes) with the same text, but different collations.  Then pick the column in order to control what language you want to search with.

Are you "comparing" strings?  If so, the collation will make a big difference -- "say" < "see" < "sch" in Czech, but not any(?) other collation.

(utf8mb4 operates the same as utf8, at least with respect to this Question.)